90/180 Rule: Residence Permit in Germany and Work Visa in Switzerland
I have an ongoing residence permit (blue card) in Germany, and I am planning to do a three-month internship in Switzerland with a work permit (La carte de légitimation).
My question is, should I still obey the 90/180 rule (due to my German residence permit) for my time in Switzerland?

Neither the time spent in Germany or Switzerland fall under the 90/180 rule (which applies only for visitors), since you have a residence permit for both. Manual: FDFA legitimation cards The legitimation card issued by the FDFA serves as a residence permit for Switzerland, ...

@MarkJohnson that should be posted as an answer, not as a comment.

@MarkJohnson, sherlockholmes, but the legitimation cards are for diplomats and others with similar privileges and immunities, so unless sherlockholmes's internship is with CERN, the UN, an embassy, or a similar entity, it wouldn't be a legitimation card but an actual residence permit.

@MarkJohnson thanks for the additional comment, mine should be a legitimation card. In case it is not I believe the answer about 90/180 still holds with an actual residence permit

Neither the time spent in Germany or Switzerland fall under the 90/180 rule (which applies only for visitors), since you have a residence permit for both.

Manual: FDFA legitimation cards


The legitimation card issued by the FDFA serves as a residence permit for Switzerland,

